# Android SQLite select

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am a beginner in android programming and I am struggling for a long time now and search on the internet but I really don't know how to solve my problem. I have difficulties to execute and understand select query from my database.

I want to select all from my table profit and to sum price columns by date in descending order. I save date as integer in my db and i just don't know what to do next.

how to sum columns by date if date is stored as integer value

my database looks like this:

```
_id | date          | price | 

 1  | 1483390870287  |1.4

2   |1483392677707  |3

3   |1483392678587  |2

4   |1483392679421  |2

5   |1483394489332  |2

6   |1483999401302  |155.4

7   |1483966599904  |333
```

Comment: date should be saved in date time format

Comment: @VivekMishra Isn't it better to save the date as long? I never checked the differences

Comment: @MateiRadu it would be easier to sort if in date format if sorting according to date

Comment: i was looking on the web and if I understood correctly there are no other option to store date in sqlite other then int or string

Comment: But a date converted to long is still sortable: more recent the date the bigger the value.

Comment: What is the desired output for the example data?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are searching something like this:

```
SELECT date, sum(price) AS price_sum
FROM table
GROUP BY date;
```

Try to get familiar with basics SQL.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_func_sum.asp

**edit**:

To *convert* timestamps in a date object:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
```

> for grouping by date you should not store your entries by second, better use days

Comment: I am familiar with sql but my problem is that dates is stored as int and i dont know what to do with that

Comment: if you don't help me I don't understand why you give me negative grade